# Cannot change Star-Rating (or change any meta-data) of files even though I own them

Tags: windows-10, permissions, metadata

So I have an external Drive with basically all my irreplaceable media on it (Photos, Videos, etc.) and I cannot alter the Metadata of these files even though I gave myself full ownership.

I can use these files normally (view, rename, delete... you name it) but cannot change anything at all in the "Details" Tab - most annoyingly the Star Ratings.

Even if I copy the Files to my Hard Drive I cannot do it on the "new file", either. So no copying back and forth to make it work.

Here's some Screenshots of how the file Data looks right now:

[They are not Read-only](https://imgur.com/lL6moY8)

[My user has full control](https://imgur.com/3T25whZ) but greyed out because of inheritance as I set the permissions on root. I can disable inheritance to make them modifyable but it changes nothing as far as being able to change Metadata goes. All 4 entries in "Group or user names" have the same permissions set.

[The menu behind the "Advanced" button looks like this](https://imgur.com/OAn4RAB). Even though I changed the owner to my user (pr0paGandhi-PC), it shows my Microsoft Account there (my full Name + Email, hence censored in the Screenshot) [I also disabled inheritance while writing this to make sure that what I'm writing is true]

[Opening the settings of my user on this page looks like this](https://imgur.com/jTXaPk6)

[Auditing](https://imgur.com/LC1Qp7Q) (Settings for User look exactly as User-Settings in Permissions Tab)

And lastly, [Effective Access tab](https://imgur.com/LA80ADe) for completeness' sake

"Previous Versions" tab in the File info is empty (no previous versions available)

[Yet clicking anything in Details does absolutely nothing.](https://imgur.com/gkmwUJ9)

I have the same problem on my normal (nonremovable) drives. [Though I can change Star Rating on **a few images**](https://imgur.com/jQsPKoO) but not others. Have not found a single video file I can change it on. The fact that I can change it on a few images makes this all the more egregious - otherwise, I would have just assumed I uninstalled the Windows function that enables the setting of meta-data...

Any ideas?

Thanks for reading through all this.

Comment: Is the external disk formatted as NTFS? Which format are the files - MP3?

Comment: Yes it's NTFS, although it doesn't really make a difference as it happens on the non-removable drives as well.

As for file format ... anything really. .mp3, .mp4, .jpg

Though as I said I can alter the metadata on __a few__ .jpg files. Have not found a single mp3 or mp4 yet. Even downloaded a test-mp4 to see if "new files" still have this problem. They do. Even freshly recorded videos recorded with Nvidia Shadowplay saved to my (non removable) D: drive cannot have their metadata edited.

Comment: Strange. Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Will do, I'll get back to you in a bit.

Comment: sfc /scannow apparently did find and fix some issues, but more importantly I continued googline and someone apparently had the same problem caused by icaros - which I am also using.

Currently stuck finishing a download, will reboot (because sfc /scannow wants me to), see if it works and if it doesn't I'll tackle the Icaros suggestion.

Comment: Nevermind I just went into Icaros and disabled the "Properties" and "Cache" options and now it works.

So well ... sorry for the spam I guess. If anyone else runs into this problem, this is the solution (for me anyways).

Thanks to both of you for taking the time! (is there some sort of thank you/upvote/commendation function here?)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was caused by the Thumbnail managing program Icaros. Disabled "Properties" and "Cache" options (not sure if both or one of them caused it, don't need to find out) and it works now.

Comment: Make backups, and check if they work.